# Waiting for segments of a progressively generated vector

Tags: c++, concurrency

I want to implement the following in C++, but I don't know which one is the simpler way of managing concurrency.

I have a thread `Producer` that is adding elements to the back of a vector `V`. Once an element is added, it is considered read-only. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume I can use a vector that does not invalidate iterators upon growing, or that I will take care of the locking with a read-write mutex. But there is a thing with the readers of the vector: they might want to access multiple consecutive elements of `V`, some of which might not has been generated yet.

At any given moment, `V` has some elements, which I will represent with "o", and there is some potential that `Producer` will add more elements, that I will represent with a "w". Thus the data in  `V` *conceptually* looks like this:

```
o o o o w w w w
```

I stress "conceptually" because I would like to not put physically in `V` elements/dummies which have not been generated yet. Now one of the readers `R` is  interested in a segment of `V` that has not been completely generated yet:

```
o o o o w w w w
    | | | |
    ---R---
```

Thus R needs to wait for `V` to grow until it contains all the elements R wants. I can have an increasing index `j` with the index of the highest generated element of `V` at any given moment. The question is, is there a simple way of making `R` to wait for a specific value of that index?

Comment: Do you have a snippet for what R currently does?

Comment: @cmh No, at this moment I'm just designing the infra-structure. But the elements of the vector would be tokens, and R is just some sort of predicate in a few consecutive tokens (not necessarily a reduction... or not a reduction at all, because I'm not doing conventional parsing).

Comment: "which one is the simpler way": what two methods have you tried?

Comment: You could wait on a condition variable until the array grows to the size you want. Are there multiple consumers? Do consumers shorten the array when they consume data from it?

Comment: @ShaunMarko, seems like a good idea. Why not put it in an answer

Comment: @arayq2 Sorry, bad wording. I intended to say "which/what is the simpler way". But for the record, I tried assigning condition variables to the positions in `V` and to the readers `R`, but then I needed to put the condition variables in containers, and then I discovered that condition variables are [not CopyConstructible, MoveConstructible, CopyAssignable, MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so based chat, I believe the problem here is not how to synchronize this *correctly*, but how to *minimize the spurious wakeup of threads that still can't progress*.

(For reference, this isn't at all the impression I got from the original question).

So, we can make a naive implementation which retains explicit control over which reader gets scheduled ...

```
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

// associate a blocked reader's desired index with the CV it waits on
struct BlockedReadToken {
    int index_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    explicit BlockedReadToken(int index) : index_(index) {}
};
struct TokenOrder {
    bool operator() (BlockedReadToken const *a,
                     BlockedReadToken const *b)
    {
        return a->index_ < b->index_;
    }
};

class BlockedReaderManager
{
    std::priority_queue<BlockedReadToken*,
                        std::vector<BlockedReadToken*>, TokenOrder> queue_;
public:
    // wait for the actual index to reach the required value
    void waitfor(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> &lock,
                 int required, int const &actual)
    {
        // NOTE: a good pooled allocator might be useful here
        // (note we only allocate while holding the lock anyway,
        // so no further synchronization is required)
        std::unique_ptr<BlockedReadToken> brt(new BlockedReadToken(required));
        queue_.push(brt.get());
        while (actual < required)
            brt->cv_.wait(lock);
    }
    // release every reader blocked waiting for the new actual index
    // (don't wake any whose condition isn't satisfied yet)
    void release(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> &lock, int actual)
    {
        while (!(queue_.empty() || queue_.top()->index_ > actual)) {
            queue_.top()->cv_.notify_one();
            queue_.pop();
        }
    }
};
```

And a wrapper around some container, which uses this blocking mechanism for readers:

```
template <typename RandomAccessContainer>
class ProgressiveContainer
{
    int size_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    BlockedReaderManager blocked_;
    RandomAccessContainer container_;
public:
    typedef typename RandomAccessContainer::size_type size_type;
    typedef typename RandomAccessContainer::value_type value_type;

    void push_back(value_type const &val) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mutex_);
        container_.push_back(val);
        ++size_;
        blocked_.release(guard, size_);
    }
    void check_readable(int index) {
        // could optimistically avoid locking with atomic size here?
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mutex_);
        if (size_ < index)
            blocked_.waitfor(guard, index, size_);
    }
    // allow un-locked [] access and require reader to call check_readable?
    value_type& operator[](int index) {
        return container_[index];
    }
    value_type& at(int index) {
        check_readable(index);
        return container_[index];
    }
};
```

Comment: I didn't intend any spurious wakeups in the first place :-) But your feedback in the chat has been invaluable, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Nice. I've created something around those lines in the meantime, but your solution takes into account a few things that I missed, like having multiple readers waiting for the same position. As per the usage of priority_queue, I have yet to make my mind; as you said probably a simpler thing will be faster in most cases. . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have one consumer, you could do something like this:

```
    ...
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    while (array.size() < targetSize) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mtx);
    }
    // read data from array
    // remove data from array consumed
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    ...
```

Comment: This could use the C++11 equivalents (or any other concurrency library), but using the size seems like the right approach ... IF nothing is removed from the array

Comment: I will have multiple readers. The previous snippet  will need that each of the waiting readers be scheduled (together with the corresponding context switch) before some of them decide to go ahead. It would be nice to have a solution that elided this.

Comment: @dsign - elided what? What should the call site look like?

Comment: @Useless Something like this: `condition_of_reader_R.wait(some_lock)`. As I said, the previous solution causes all waiting R's to be scheduled just to check if they are ready to run.

Comment: That doesn't look like something accessing an array. What should the reader code _logically_ look like?

Comment: ... and, I think I understand. You're worried about a thundering herd wakeup when a single element is appended to the array? Are you sure it's a real problem, or does it just feel inelegant?

Comment: @Useless: An example: `void r(V const& v) { /*Wait until jr+2 be ready, then*/ if ( v[jr].token_type == ')' && v[jr+1].token_type == '\n' && v[jr+2]=='var' ) { /* Can insert ";" (in new token stream) */ } else { /* something else */ } }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22345/discussion-between-dsign-and-useless)